# Keep &nbsp entities in rails sanitize

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using either the rails sanitize method, or any gems (such as the sanitize gem), it is possible to keep certain tags, but also keep certain html elements such as &nbsp.

So far I have only found options for keeping tags and attributes, but not elements.

Thanks,
Owen

Comment: you should probably look at Nokogiri

Comment: Nokogiri is meant for complex HTML or XML transformations. guessing from your question that might be tool you're looking for.

Comment: The parts of HTML like `&nbsp;` and `&amp;` are called “entities”, not “elements”. “Elements” are the parts like `<body>…</body>` and `<img src="cat.gif">`. You want to allow certain *entities*, not certain *elements*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use entity number instead of entity name for allowed tags option.

For the `&nbsp;` - entity number is `&#160;`

if a variable has value `Hello <br>User</br>, how&#160;old&#160;are&#160;you?`
, in a rails view it could look

```
sanitize(text_with_html, tags: %w(br &#160;))
```

It's checked for rails 6.1, but I suppose it works for previous versions also